# Why is Django unable to read the "username" value from the request?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I was working on Django restframework (DRF) where I would send a video along with some json data with the format `{"username":"____"}` but if I send file along JSON it wouldn't read the JSON, saying the key doesn't exist.

This is the backend side:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def video_analysis(request):
    print(request.data['username'])

    try:
        q = Users.objects.get()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error : ",str(e))
    file_obj = request.FILES['file']
    destination_file = 'file.mp4'  # Replace with the desired destination path and file name

    with open(destination_file, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
            file.write(chunk)

    return Response({'message': 'File saved successfully.'})
```

I am using this Python snippet to check API

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/analysis/'

file_path = "video.mp4"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
with open(file_path,'rb') as file:
    files = {'file':file}
    response = requests.post(url,json={"username":"swin"},files = files)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json)
```

The backend side throws error when I try to access the username field, but when i do the same except remove the file field from the testing snippet, it is able to access username field.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `data` instead of the `json` field, i.e., `requests.post(url, data={"username":"swin"},files = files)`?